# How to compile IEEE Access templates with XeLaTeX with fontspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

The template is accessible here:

http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/

Some editing is made to make the template compatible for Linux:

1. `mv logo.png Logo.png`
2. `mv notaglinelogo.png notaglineLogo.png`

Some editing is made to make package compatible with xelatex:

Edit the `ieeeaccess.cls` file:

1. Replace `\RequirePackage{color}` with `\RequirePackage{xcolor}`
2. Replace `\RequirePackage{spotcolor}` with `\RequirePackage{xespotcolor}`

Now the `access.tex` is compilable with `xelatex`.

However, if I add `fontspec` package, I get unreasonable `\c_sys_year_int` error, listed as following:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./access.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(./ieeeaccess.cls (./IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 503.

-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using DVI output.
-- This is a 10 point document.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 1090.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 1090.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/ptm/bx/n' instead on input line 1090.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xespotcolor/xespotcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everypage/everypage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.22516 ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int  { \tex_year:D }

?
```

How can I eliminate this issue?

Comment: You should also change the font setup, as you see the class wants to use Times, but it can't with `fontspec` loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class redefines the primitive `\year` and this confuses expl3.

Load expl3 before the class:

```
 \RequirePackage{expl3}
 \documentclass{ieeeaccess}
```

Comment: Is it better to use `\RequirePackage{fontspec}`? That way you still get the required times fonts in the document as well as the ability to use other ttf or otf fonts.

Comment: @DavidPurton I didn't really check, but normally I would load fontspec later to give it a chance to overwrite unsuitable things from the class (like the font encoding) and then reset the fonts myself.