# \textsc in IEEE Access Template

Tags: small-caps

I am struggling to use `\textsc` in the IEEE Access Template that can be downloaded from [here](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/).

To be able to compile it in Linux, I had to change the name of the logos as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418954/how-to-compile-ieee-access-templates-with-xelatex-with-fontspec). After that, everything is compiled successfully and I do not get any errors, however then `\textsc` commands are just ignored in all places except for the title. I do not know why this is happening. Can anybody shed some light on this?

I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

I am using TeXstudio and pdfLaTeX.

Thank you in advance for the time you take in answering.

Mininimal working example:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation \textsc{of} Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}}


\begin{abstract}
These \textsc{instructions} give you guidelines for preparing your     abstract.

\end{abstract}


\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a \textsc{template} for \LaTeX. 
\EOD

\end{document}
```

In this example, the `\textsc` command in the title works but the ones in the abstract or in the introduction do not work.

EDIT: I am using Linux

Comment: Please include a minimal work example for us to better assist you.

Comment: I think that is a minimal example. Anyway, the template is linked in the question, thank you zzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile your given code on current MiKTeX 2.9 with `pdflatex mwe.tex`, I get three warnings, resulting in the following lines of class `ieeeaccess.cls`:

```
\ifpdf
 \pdfmapfile{+ t1-times.map}
 \pdfmapfile{+ t1-formata.map}
 \pdfmapfile{+ t1-giovannistd.map}
\fi
```

That means at last I do not have the needed fonts installed on my system, and I suppose, it is the same on your computer.

The generell issue here is, that not all fonts families do have an font for `\textsc{...}`. The usual fallback is to use the standard font.

With loading the three pdfmapfiles above the class tried to use the fonts the journal is using. But it failed.

You have three possibilitys:

1. Install the needed fonts (ask the journal which fonts they use) or try if overleaf has installed this fonts on their template for ieeeaccess.
2. Ignore the missing sc-font, but make sure, that the journal can reproduce it.
3. Do not use sc-font.

Comment: I have tried the same minimal working example in overleaf, and it still doesn't work despite not rendering any error or warning. Mysteriously, one thing that did work was to wrap the `\textsc{}` with a `\textit{}` like this: `These \textit{\textsc{instructions}} give you ...`, but I don't want to pollute my document with a bunch of `\textit{}` that don't actually have the purpose of making text italic. Do you have any idea of how to address this?

Comment: I figured out a solution (see the answer that I have posted) but would love to understand why it works and why it is needed in this specific template.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this is needed, but I could get `\textsc{}` to work by redefining the command, adding this to preamble of my document:

```
\def\textsc#1{\textnormal{{\sc #1}}}%
```