# Problem with siunitx package together with rmstyle.cls

Tags: errors, siunitx, expl3

could somebody point out what to change in [rmstyle.cls](http://rmseura.tkk.fi/rmlehti/docs/rmstyle.cls) file to get siunitx working?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{rmstyle}[12pt]
% \documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\volume{XX}
\issue{Y}
\year{20ZZ}
\doilabel{12345}
\title{
MWE siunitx problem
}

\author{First Author\footnote{Corresponding author. \texttt{first.author@xx.yy}}, Second Author and Third Author
}


\begin{document}
\SI{3}{mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is going wrong for you? For me, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I am using Overleaf, where it doesn't work: https://www.overleaf.com/1462967519gxqkdvypmnwm

Comment: The class redefines the TeX primitive `\year`, which `siunitx` (or rather `expl3`) needs, but the class also needs its definition of `\year`, so we need to juggle with `\year` a bit. Add `\newcommand*{\texyear}{}\newcommand*{\classyear}{}\let\texyear\year` before you load the class. Directly after you load the class call `\let\classyear\year\let\year\texyear` *before* you load `siunitx`. After you have loaded `siunitx` call `\let\year\classyear`.

Comment: Aha! Much easier: Just load `\RequirePackage{expl3}` *before* the documentclass. No need to juggle with `\year` at all. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418954/35864

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you want to make it as an answer? I am new to this forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Just like `ieeeaccess`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418954/35864) the class `rmstyle` redefines the primitive `\year`. The original definition of `\year` is needed by `expl3` (which is loaded by `siunitx`) to work properly.

You can circumvent the issue by loading `expl3` even before the document class as suggested by Ulrike Fischer in her answer to [How to compile IEEE Access templates with XeLaTeX with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418968/35864)

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\documentclass[12pt]{rmstyle}
```

note that documentlcass options like `12pt` should be given in square brackets before the class name not afterwards.