# I am unable to write Urdu text (words/sentences) in IEEE Access Overleaf template

Tags: xetex

I need to write some Urdu text in IEEE Access paper. If I am changing compiler to XeLaTeX then I am getting incorrect format of the paper. Can anyone please help to work it out?

The following is a sample of IEEE Access Template with Urdu text.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{fontspec}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic, Language=Urdu, Scale=1.0]{majallab.ttf}

\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

This is a sample of Urdu text~\urdufont{سستی} \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont~but it is not supported in IEEE Access. This is a single Urdu character~\urdufont{ﺴ}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont~it is also not supported. How can I be able to include the~\textAR{کمیونیکیشن}, text? 

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX! It would really help us out of you give us a bit more details: First, could you create a Minimal Working Example (MWE) that we can run on our side and recreate the problem. Second, could you specify exactly where the difference in format is? i.e. what do you expect to get, and what did you get using XeLaTeX?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am compiling IEEE Access with XeLeTex compiler, but it does not show the output. I am using fontspec package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't link to an external website, this link will soon be dead. Show a small, complete example here.

Comment: I have updated the question with MWE.

Comment: I am having trouble running ieeeacces with XeLaTeX. I do believe it is designed specifically for pdflatex. Even if I run it without any languages and simply with a title and some sample text it gives out plenty of errors. What I'm trying to say is that the problem is not with your code or with urdu but rather with the document class that does not support XeLaTeX...

Comment: Try having a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418954/how-to-compile-ieee-access-templates-with-xelatex-with-fontspec